# GCM device is always unregistered

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

After a lot of searching and following this guide https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging

The response from my post requests is always returning the error below, despite the fact that my device has been registered. Also i don't know if that helps but i am using android studio in order to deploy my application.

```
{"multicast_id":xxxxx,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

This is my code inside my first activity

```
private GCMClientManager mPushClientManager;
    private final String PROJECT_NUMBER = "kkkkkk";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPushClientManager = new GCMClientManager(this, PROJECT_NUMBER);
    mPushClientManager.registerIfNeeded(new GCMClientManager.RegistrationCompletedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String registrationId, boolean isNewRegistration) {
            Toast.makeText(ChoicesActivity.this, registrationId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("test", "regId " + registrationId);
            // SEND async device registration to your back-end server
            // linking user with device registration id
            // POST https://my-back-end.com/devices/register?user_id=123&device_id=abc
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String ex) {
            super.onFailure(ex);
            // If there is an error registering, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off when retrying.
        }
    });
}
```

This is my GCMClientManager

```
public class GCMClientManager {
    // Constants
    public static final String TAG = "GCMClientManager";
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    // Member variables
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private String regid;
    private String projectNumber;
    private Activity activity;

    public static abstract class RegistrationCompletedHandler {
        public abstract void onSuccess(String registrationId, boolean isNewRegistration);
        public void onFailure(String ex) {
            // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off.
            Log.e(TAG, ex);
        }
    }

    public GCMClientManager(Activity activity, String projectNumber) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.projectNumber = projectNumber;
        this.gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(activity);
    }

    // Register if needed or fetch from local store
    public void registerIfNeeded(final RegistrationCompletedHandler handler) {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            regid = getRegistrationId(getContext());

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground(handler);
            } else { // got id from cache
                Log.i(TAG, regid);
                handler.onSuccess(regid, false);
            }
        } else { // no play services
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground(final RegistrationCompletedHandler handler) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getContext());
                    }
                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getContext());
                    regid = instanceID.getToken(projectNumber, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    Log.i(TAG, regid);

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(getContext(), regid);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                    handler.onFailure("Error :" + ex.getMessage());
                }
                return regid;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String regId) {
                if (regId != null) {
                    handler.onSuccess(regId, true);
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }

        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getContext().getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(),
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        return activity;
    }

    private Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

And this is my GCMMessageHandler

```
public class GCMMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {
    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");

        createNotification(from, message);
    }

    // Creates notification based on title and body received
    private void createNotification(String title, String body) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Also my AndroidManifest.xml has the following inside

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- gcm -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.demo.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demo.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.demo.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="test"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo" >

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.GCMMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my script in which i am making the post requests

```
REGISTRATION_ID=xxxxxx

SERVER_KEY=xxxxx

curl --header "Authorization: key=$SERVER_KEY" --header  Content-Type:"application/json"  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d  "{ \"data\" : {\"foo\": \"bar\"}, \"registration_ids\":[\"$REGISTRATION_ID\"]  }"
```

Answer (score 0):

GCM response 'Not Registered' means following "If it is NotRegistered, you should remove the registration ID from your server database because the application was uninstalled from the device or it does not have a broadcast receiver configured to receive com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE intents." from documentation. Check in what case you get this error, when app is uninstalled from device or your describe incorrect broadcastreceiver in AndroidManifest. You can test your GCM functionallity with my test gcm server. Hope, this help you.